# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS cannot suspend / fails on suspending

Tags: suspend, 16.04

I have recently upgraded my desktop to Ubuntu 16.04. I had one problem with it before, which was that the Unity Launcher and status bar were missing. I solved this with [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).
However, when I try to suspend my machine, the following occurs:
The hard drive will save the last bits of data and will turn itself off.
But the thing is: the computer itself is still turned on. This means I am stuck with no screen input, and it forces me to push the reset button on my computer case, as I can't take control of my pc anymore.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think you should put in your question what is your hardware, probably what's your computer model and brand. Suspend/resume depends highly on what type of hardware it is running.

Comment: This problem has already been solved by a clean install.

Comment: @DaveTraver Welcome to Ask Ubuntu :) . I just saw your [suggested edit](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/626010) , which seems to be intended to address the author. If you wish to answer the quesrion, please write it an post in the box given at the end of this page  .

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem, although it seems to be a bug rather some kind of misconfiguration, so there is nothing we can do about it right now. Let's hope the fix will be released soon. There is related bug report you can follow: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302

**EDIT**

In discussion from the link above, someone pointed out that the bug was fixed in kernel 4.4.8 and in fact it solves the problem *for me*. That means the issue was identified and we can expect an update in a few days.

If you're impatiant like me and you know what you're doing, you can install the new kernel by yourself from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/

Comment: Hey Kuba, thanks for the link. I'll be sure to check back regularly.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! BTW, why are they waiting with the official update through software updater so long?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but this unfortunately didn't work for me. Assuming others do get this problem solved, I'll upvote your answer

Comment: booting up with Kernel 4.2.0 worked for me

Comment: Instructions to install the new kernel are given on [this bug report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1574125/comments/26).

Comment: 4.4.8 did not fix it for me.  My laptop is an HP DV7 with Radeon 7960M XT graphics.  Suspend worked fine in Kubuntu, but doesn't work in Ubuntu for some reason...

Comment: @XToro Fixed for Dell Inspiron 3537 with kernel v4.5.3-generic

Comment: Fixed the problem for me on a Samsung Chronos 700Z5A (updating to kernel 4.4.8) (for sake of google-fu). Ah, the joy of upgrading...

Comment: Update to 4.4.8 fixed the problem for me. Dell inspiron 3537.

Comment: The upgrade of the kernel fix the issue for me,  and when I uninstalled that update hoping to get back to the previous one, it corrupted my OS and I had to reinstall it completely again! I would not recommend this unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Update to 4.4.8 and **not** fixed the problem for me. Dell inspiron P49G.

Comment: Also have this problem since 16.04. The Ubuntu bug report is dead end - one of the usual people going around closing things that aren't fixed. For me not fixed even on 4.8.11 (proposed), and not fixed at any point since first 16.04 release. About 1 in 5 suspends fails in some way. Most suspend debugging instructions seem out of date.

Comment: @SamBrightman I'm having the same problem on my old Lenovo ThinkPad Edge running 4.4.8-040408-generic.  About 1 in 5 suspends fails, with the following behavior: the screen goes black, and the computer looks like it went into suspend, but I can hear that it has not.  I close the lid, as usual, but then when I open the lid, it doesn't come back to life, and it's frozen.  The power key does nothing to wake it, unless I keep it held down for about 10 seconds to hard reboot.  Also, Ctrl+Alt+F2 doesn't even work to bring up a new terminal/login prompt.

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.9.28-040928-generic kernel and it didn't help.  After upgrading and rebooting, I got locked out on the very first suspend.

Comment: I just noticed that if I invoke `sudo pm-suspend` on the command line (rather than selecting suspend from the menu) it seems to work fine!! (well, at the least it hasn't failed yet; I have made five attempts from the command line and all worked; again, I'm using kernel 4.9.28, on a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge 13). It would be interesting to know if this solves the problem for anyone else as well.

Comment: I am with kernel 4.10.0 and still suspend is not working... Ubuntu 16.04 and nvidia VGA