# Ubuntu 16.04 is not providing working suspend or hibernate feature

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate, overheating

I previously used 14.04 and i used to suspend when ever i am done and need to resume my task later . That shuts my machine down(except the LED indicator) which didn't consume power and no heating so i could put my lappy in bag causing no heating problem and whenever i turned it on it resumed to my previous state....(All was OK till then.)

But now in 16.04 it is not shutting down after suspend or hibernate only screen is getting shut but backlights are still on and this state consume battery and i can not put my lappy in bag cause it gets overheated.
And i cant even turn it on to make a proper shut down(In this case i need to do a force shut-down /long press power buton)
How can i have the same functionality like i had in 14.04 
Hibernating without heating(power consumption).

Comment: Affects me to. Some say update bios, but it doesn't help. Has anyone solved this issue by upgrading to kernel 4.5?

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2306262) can be useful. I tried to enter the various commands, but unsuccesfully, since I don't understand what the comments mean (maybe just because of my bad english..).

Comment: nothing work for me!

Comment: I works for me with kernel version `4.4.0-22`. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761758/ubuntu-16-04-lts-cannot-suspend-fails-on-suspending#comment1140670_761828) @JoeBergevin reported that it works with `4.2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have installed your proprietory graphics drivers (dash -> software and updates -> additional drivers). if it still doesnt work, check https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend link and troubleshoot to find the problem (kernel testing facility). hope it helps.

Comment: not working after updating additional drivers!

Comment: did u diagnose as given in the link? also share which system you have and graphics hardware.