# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't shut down after suspend or hibernate

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown, hibernate

### Why no answer accepted

For the simple reason that I haven't been using Ubuntu for a long time, so I couldn't test the answers.

### The question

Actually my question can appear identical to [this one in this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762473/ubuntu-16-04-is-not-providing-working-suspend-or-hibernate-feature) (and also [this one elsewhere](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321399)); indeed the *question* is the same, but I'm asking it anyway because I can give more informations and because I tried some solution found on the web (possibly getting things worse).

I used to hibernate Ubuntu 15.10 (closing the lid).
Now that I've updated it to 16.04 (I thought it was a good thing, since this version is LTS, unlike the 15.10), I cannot use hibernation (nor suspension!) anymore: if I try to use it, Ubuntu doesn't shut down, just the screen goes black, the power led is on, and I cannot do anything else than shutting it down manually (long press of the power button).
When I power it on again, I see the following lines

[image]

then Ubuntu boots up.

From [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate) I tried with

```
sudo -s
echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

and

```
sudo -s
echo platform > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

Only the first partially worked and only once: by partially I mean that after the brutal shut down the session was recovered.

Then I tried to follow [this suggestion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2306262). I didn't understand the comments written after the commands, so I literally entered the commands as they are (thinking that some error like "this command/folder doesn't exist" would have been occurred if there was something to substitute in the commands):

**EDIT**

```
cat /proc/meminfo
sudo swapoff -a
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=8M
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile && sudo mkswap /swapfile && sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo -b gedit /etc/fstab
free -m
swapon

mount | grep " / "
sudo blkid -g
sudo blkid
sudo filefrag -v /swapfile | grep "First block:"
sudo filefrag -v /swapfile
echo "resume=UUID=cdXX--X18 resume_offset=66050" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
sudo -b gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
sudo -b gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... resume=UUID=cdXX--X18 resume_offset=66050"
sudo update-grub -y
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Maybe this has been a terrible idea, since now I get this.

[image: IMG:]

In the end I found the question linked above and I went [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend), but I don't know what to do.

**EDIT 2** At the moment if I enter

```
...$ sudo swapon -s
```

I obtain absolutely nothing

```
...$
```

Comment: Maybe it's because of the BIOS. In my BIOS, I go to Power Management and there should be an option on what to do when suspend. Normally mine is S1 but S3 is the thing.

Comment: Stab in the dark here but you should investigate your BIOS settings and go over them. Get out your manual and check through it. I've had countless issues in the past that have had a BIOS switch as the solution.

Comment: Undo the very bad idea. This was a proof-of-concept how to get Ubuntu to use the swap space for hibernation. As root with sudo, remove the added last line from `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`and the added two resume stanzas from `etc/default/grub`, run the last two lines to update grub and the initrd. Delete /swapfile. Run `sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`. Try any of these targets with `sudo systemctl suspend`. What happens?

Comment: In the end I decided to reinstall ubuntu 15.10. Now hibernation works again. Maybe I will install 16.04 on another partition. When I'll do so, I will refer to this question and answers.

Answer (score 10):

### Forcing hibernate to power off the machine:

After looking around a long time for an answer to this that actually addressed the issue (not related ones), I found a tip [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils#Computer_does_not_turn_off_when_hibernating) which got the job done for me:

Create a file in the `pm` config directory:

```
sudo vim /etc/pm/config.d/hibernate_mode
```

that sets the variable `HIBERNATE_MODE` like so:

```
HIBERNATE_MODE="shutdown"
```

After doing this, hibernate powered down the machine on completion like expected. An explanation for what setting `HIBERNATE_MODE` does is in the manual for [pm-hibernate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pm-hibernate):

> Default method to power down the system when
>   hibernating. If not set, the system will use the kernel default as a
>   default value. Check /sys/power/disk for valid values. The default
>   value will be surrounded by [square brackets].

My default in that file was `platform`. Setting the variable above to `shutdown` overrides this, and gets what we want happening.

### Related information and tips for getting hibernate to work correctly:

As for those "related issues" everyone seems to have with hibernating, quick debugging tips:

1. **Check that the command `sudo pm-hibernate` actually does something.** If not, none of these other tips will make any difference. If it doesn't work, ensure 1) the size of your swap partition is greater than that of your RAM and 2) secure boot is disabled in your BIOS.
2. Only once that command works, look at integrating hibernate into your system as you please. A couple of common ones:

   - **Add hibernate to the Ubuntu menu:** [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/118601) seems to be the best answer to me. [Official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) also has a slightly different version.
     Note: once hibernate is added to the Ubuntu menu, you may also need to fix the alternative call to `sudo systemctl hibernate`. Apparently, (at least for Ubuntu 16.04) the Ubuntu menu option calls `sudo systemctl hibernate` instead of `sudo pm-hibernate`. `systemctl hibernate` was fixed for me by adding the following content to file `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`:

     > [Sleep]
     >   HibernateMode=shutdown

     If the file doesn't exists yet, you can create it. More info [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/systemd-sleep.conf.5.html).
   - **Change the behaviour of the power button (by default it displays in interactive menu):** To change it to directly hibernate, or shutdown you need to modify the associated [gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/a/74419) entry. A lot of other answers go through the GUI way if that floats your boat. To see the available options use `gsettings range org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04:

- Closing the lid did not do anything
- Manually suspending with the menu item in the system tray resulted in a half suspended state with the only way out to reset the system.

I solved these issues by

1. upgrading the kernel to 4.4.8 (after this suspend from menu worked for me)
2. Adding the line `HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend` to /etc/systemd/logind.conf (wich made the lid switch to work again).

I think both issues are bugs that should be fixed (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1574120).

Comment: Did this solve the problem for suspension only, or also for hibernation?

Answer (score 2):

By seeing your last image and **EDIT 2**, I can understand that Ubuntu can't find a Swap Partition on your system. So I suggest you should create a Swap partition equal to or larger than your RAM size, and try again by running

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

You can create swap partition using GParted, run this to install it

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hibernate has been disabled by default.**

Try this

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

> If the hibernate test works, you can continue to use the sudo
>   pm-hibernate command when you want to hibernate.
>
> You can also enable the hibernate option in the menus. To do that, use
>   your favorite text editor to create
>   /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla.
>   Add the following to the file and save:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

[Read More on Hibernation 16.04 from this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)

To Shutdown

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

To Restart

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: As I written, sudo pm-hibernate used to work very well before upgrading form 15.10 to 16.04LTS. So the problem should concern the 16.04LTS version. In addition, maybe I did something very wrong following instruction without understanding them. Could you help me in correcting these problems?