# Can't set HIBERNATE_MODE = "shutdown" in /etc/pm/config.d/

Tags: nvidia, suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate

I am trying to fix hibernate on my desktop.  I am running a x99 motherboard, Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.8.0-41-generic, and nvidia-370.

I can successfully hibernate by manually setting `/sys/power/disk` to `shutdown` instead of the default `platform` and manually telling the kernel to hibernate. I learned how to do this from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate.

`sudo -s
echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state`

This works nearly perfectly.  There are some slight graphical issues with the task bar that go away when you click on it.  Also, my nvidia settings get slightly reset.  I can live with that.  The other versions of nvidia driver I have tried crash hard.

When the value is `platform` my PC will not shut all the way down.  I have to hard power off.  However, when I restart the state is resumed correctly.  Only when I manually force it hibernate and manual set the value `shutdown` does my PC shut off and state is resumed.

Since this worked, tried to make my `/sys/power/disk` default to `shutdown` instead of platform. I followed the advice of https://askubuntu.com/a/837334/154184 but the value seems stay `platform`.

`jophde@pyre:~$ sudo cat /etc/pm/config.d/hibernate_mode 
HIBERNATE_MODE="shutdown"`

I believe my file permissions are correct since there are the same as the defaults file.

`jophde@pyre:~$ sudo ls -lah /etc/pm/config.d/hibernate_mode 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26 Mar 22 02:32 /etc/pm/config.d/hibernate_mode
jophde@pyre:~$ sudo ls -lah /usr/lib/pm-utils/defaults 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.0K Mar 22 01:52 /usr/lib/pm-utils/defaults`

The code that gets run when you run `sudo pm-hibernate` and reads in these values is `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions`.  The part that sets the values from the defaults and user configs seems a bit hacky so maybe there is a bug there?

`for cfg in "${PM_UTILS_ETCDIR}"/config.d/*[!~] \
           "${PM_UTILS_ETCDIR}/${STASHNAME}.config.d"/*[!~]; do
        [ -f "$cfg" ] || continue
        # Ugly, I know. The goal here is to allow multiple files in
        # /etc/pm/config.d declare these variables and have those 
        # declarations add together instead of the last one overwriting
        # all the others.
        [ "$SUSPEND_MODULES" ] && REAL_SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES"
        [ "$HOOK_BLACKLIST" ] && REAL_HOOK_BLACKLIST="$HOOK_BLACKLIST"
        [ "$ADD_PARAMETERS" ] && REAL_ADD_PARAMETERS="$ADD_PARAMETERS"
        [ "$DROP_PARAMETERS" ] && REAL_DROP_PARAMETERS="$DROP_PARAMETERS"
        set -a
        . "${cfg}"
        SUSPEND_MODULES="$REAL_SUSPEND_MODULES $SUSPEND_MODULES"
        HOOK_BLACKLIST="$REAL_HOOK_BLACKLIST $HOOK_BLACKLIST"
        ADD_PARAMETERS="$REAL_ADD_PARAMETERS $ADD_PARAMETERS"
        DROP_PARAMETERS="$REAL_DROP_PARAMETERS $DROP_PARAMETERS"
        set +a
done`

I don't have any other configs in `/etc/pm/config.d/` and I did not modify 
`/usr/lib/pm-utils/defaults`.

How do I get `HIBERNATE_MODE="shutdown"` to work with Ubuntu Hibernate menu item and `pm-hibernate`?

https://linux.die.net/man/8/pm-hibernate