# Ubuntu won't shut down after previously waking up from hibernation

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, swap, hibernate, ubuntu-mate

**Background:**

I was having trouble with hibernation, because my swap was on an encrypted logical volume that generated a random key for every session. I then followed a guide on Ubuntu's website to make it use a fixed key every time. Hibernation started working properly.

**The problem:**

Although my laptop can hibernate properly now (goes into hibernation, asks me for swap encryption key while wake up and wakes up properly), the problem is that *after* waking up from hibernation, some time later (doesn't matter how much time) if I try to shut it down, it won't shut down.
I have tried the shut down button, restart button, the commands:

```
sudo shutdown 0
systemctl poweroff -i
poweroff
```

etc., but no luck. It goes into a halfway shutdown and freezes. It forces me to brute-shutdown, and that's not the way to go.

**Log**

I repeated the whole thing again, this time to capture logs, so separated all processes temporally by minutes. Here's what was happening (what I was doing) at the respective time:

18:03 Attempt hibernation - successful at 18:04
18:05 Attempt resume - successful, completed at 18:06
18:10 attempt shut down - system frozen. Waiting.
18:15 nothing happening. Forcefully shutting down using hardware power button.
18:17 begin boot - successful, completed at 18:18 (total time 33.618s)

Here's the kernel log:
https://pastebin.com/vCeitB81

See the image below. It is the situation *after* I have run the command `poweroff` in the terminal. The screen has frozen and nothing further happens. Same things happens with each of the other commands mentioned above.
[image]

Comment: look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/767679/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-shut-down-after-suspend-or-hibernate

Comment: @tso I saw that question earlier, and it deals with getting hibernation to shutdown laptop after finishing hibernation. It is not related to the issue I am facing.

Comment: yeah :/ i hope, someone can help u. it's really strange.

Comment: added logs. do you have anything to say on that? @tso