# Thinkpad E560 cannot sleep on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: gnome, suspend, 16.04, hibernate

Hello fellow Ubuntu users,

I freshly installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad E560. When I close the lid of the notebook, it does not seem suspend whatsoever. The indicator led stays on whereas on Windows it flashes a few times and stays in a breathing state.

After a bit of research, it looks like a few people had a similar issues in which they could not wake up their Thinkpads. The cause of the problem seemed to be a bug with a USB3 driver, but as the posts regarding it are two years in the past, I suspect that these bugs should be fixed by now.

Sadly, I am not too experienced with Linux, so I don't really have any idea on how to debug this problem. Therefore I would appreciate any help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing a quick Google search, I found another Thinkpad E560 user from September 2015 lamenting the poor Linux support: "Linux users should avoid the E560, at least until driver support has radically improved." [link](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?t=118979) 

It seems the E560 model just isn't as well-supported as most thinkpads are under Linux/Ubuntu. That said, there are some very clever folks on here, maybe one of them can help. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS cannot suspend / fails on suspending](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761758/ubuntu-16-04-lts-cannot-suspend-fails-on-suspending)

Comment: @chaskes, see my answer to this post

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I saw your answer. Your answer is just a link to another question, which makes it a dupe. Both boil down to Q: I can't suspend/resume, A: use mainline kernel. :)

Comment: I'm having same issue with Dell Inspiron 3537.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like said problem was yet again a general bug.

Thanks to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761758/ubuntu-16-04-lts-cannot-suspend-fails-on-suspending), I installed an upstream kernel which solved the problem.