# Suspend not working on Lenovo Yoga 510-15ISK

Tags: suspend, lenovo

I have witness two issues:

1. When closing the lid it sometimes doesn't suspend.
2. When opening the lid again it usually just displays a black screen and doesn't wake up again.

Possibly relevant information:

This machine has an amd gpu and I am running 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Related to [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS cannot suspend / fails on suspending](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761758/ubuntu-16-04-lts-cannot-suspend-fails-on-suspending) ?

> I have the same problem, although it seems to be a bug rather some kind >of misconfiguration, so there is nothing we can do about it right now. >Let's hope the fix will be released soon. There is related bug report you >can follow: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302
>
> EDIT
>
> In discussion from the link above, someone pointed out that the bug was  >fixed in kernel 4.4.8 and in fact it solves the problem for me. That
> the issue was identified and we can expect an update in a few days.

Comment: I found a reasonable fix for me which was to disable the AMD graphics chip. That somehow got rid of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Found the solution on another forum. The problem is with two GPU's, Intel & Nvidia. If Nvdia is the default GPU, suspend and hibernate will have issues.

1. Run `nvidia-settings`.
2. In "PRIME Profiles" tab, select the GPU as "Intel" instead of "NVIDIA".
3. Save and restart your machine.

Let me know in comments if this solution works in Ubuntu 16.0.4. I tried this on 14.0.4 and it worked.

Edit: The solution also works in Ubuntu 16.0.4. I upgraded my 14.0.4 to 16.0.4 and this issue didn't reappear.