# wifi doesnt work after upgrading to 16.04 (Module wl not found)

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

Have tried almost everything on the internet. Have turned off the secure boot via bios too.

1. `sudo modprobe wl` returns `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.8-040408-generic`
2. `dkms status` returns

   ```
   bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
   bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
   bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
   broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271: added
   nvidia-367, 367.57, 4.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
   psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.0, 3.13.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
   virtualbox, 5.0.24, 4.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
   ```
3. `modinfo wl` returns `modinfo: ERROR: Module wl not found.`
4. `dpkg -l *broadcom*` returns

   ```
   Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
   +++-==============-============-============-=================================
   un  broadcom-sta-c <none>       <none>       (no description available)
   ii  broadcom-sta-d 6.30.223.271 all          dkms source for the Broadcom STA 
   un  broadcom-sta-m <none>       <none>       (no description available)
   un  broadcom-sta-s <none>       <none>       (no description available)
   ```

Output of wireless-info script (https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info):

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Nov 2016 20:26 IST +0530

Booted last: 10 Nov 2016 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.8-040408-generic #201604200335 SMP Wed Apr 20 07:37:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]
    Kernel modules: bcma

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 24ae:2000  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:029d Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid Library

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s20u2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s20u2' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.14  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fb79:8f5c:f1c4:a912/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9785 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7227879 (7.2 MB)  TX bytes:2233132 (2.2 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF3]>  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr0-nic Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0-nic' [IF4]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s20u2  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s20u2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s20u2
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s20u2
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      6693     1  0 20:22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         virbr0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBridge
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'virbr0' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       virbr0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     virbr0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       5686f0c7-25f2-4c61-b227-a5f554e2f08a
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
BRIDGE.SLAVES:                          
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{25}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   5686f0c7-25f2-4c61-b227-a5f554e2f08a | virbr0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.122.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20u2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         motorola
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Moto G (4)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20u2' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/net/enp0s20u2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20u2
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       1f942f32-cd1f-30e0-85af-891edd75ee41
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{23}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   1f942f32-cd1f-30e0-85af-891edd75ee41 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.14/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.14
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1478793178
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = uz510
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::fb79:8f5c:f1c4:a912/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:08:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         virbr0-nic
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceTun
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tun
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.6
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'virbr0-nic' [IF4]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       virbr0-nic
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Digisol]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Digisol | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Digisol | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

virbr0-nic  no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s20u2  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

virbr0-nic  Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s20u2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4365 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (r8188eu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"

##### dmesg #############################

[  670.713389] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[  674.981001] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[  674.981006] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[  675.391287] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  675.561144] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[  675.561210] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  675.562031] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u2: link is not ready
[  919.516217] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  919.689147] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[  919.689213] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 1002.937149] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 1002.937214] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 1095.837161] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 1095.837217] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 1107.859606] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u2: link is not ready
[ 1107.860981] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 1108.033148] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 1108.033217] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Have a look at this Ubuntu Forums thread entitled "[I upgraded, and now I have this error...](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946145)".

Comment: You need to install `broadcom-sta-dkms`.

Comment: @heynnema already did.. still doesnt work.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `dkms status` and `modinfo wl`... and `dpkg -l *broadcom*`.

Comment: @heynnema added

Comment: You have an unsupported kernel. That is why the module does not build.

Comment: @Pilot6 I had to manually upgrade the kernel because of a suspend problem, which got fixed. After upgrade, everything(including suspend) is working properly except wifi.

Comment: Problems with unsupported kernels are off-topic at this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP broke the system by manually installing another kernel.

Comment: You're welcome to ask on [unix.se] though. (Hint: use ctrl+k after highlighting a block of code to format it, or put four spaces before it rather than using backticks)

Comment: @Neal You might want to boot with your 4.4.0-47 kernel already installed instead of 4.4.8. Perhaps you meant to install 4.8.4 for Intel BayTrail bug fix instead???

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Nope, I installed the correct one. btw I rebooted in my old kernel(where the suspend problem was), purged the new kernel, and started using intel graphic card instead of nvidia's. After that all is fixed and I am running ubuntu smoothly now.

Comment: @guntbert it is ironic that I did the previous steps following answer from askubuntu(http://askubuntu.com/a/761828/594165) which made my question off-topic!

Comment: Why is installing another kernel off topic? I don't see why this was closed, I am voting to reopen.

Comment: @MarkKirby: It isn't but dealing with the consequences (like broken DKMS modules) is. Though I guess we could interpret the question as "How do I tell DKMS to compile a module for the current kernel?" which happens to be the solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're running kernel 4.4.8, then none of your dkms modules got built for the new kernel, including the broadcom-sta-dkms that you just added.

To get the broadcom-sta-dkms installed, you'll need to:

1. open terminal
2. type `sudo dkms build broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271`
3. type `sudo dkms install broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271`

then `dkms status` should have changed from:

```
broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271: added
```

to:

```
broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271: 4.4.8-040408-generic, x86_64: installed
```

and:

```
modinfo wl #(should now work)
```

You'll need to perform somewhat similar actions on your other dkms modules to get them working again. Secure boot should remain off in the BIOS.

Comment: well it did work. wifi is working now but suspend is broken again. The reason I had to upgrade my kernal manually was because suspend was not working. Looks like I am back to square one :(

Comment: Remember that the rest of your dkms modules are broken too. Did you manually install a newer kernel? How much RAM, how much swap? Please vote/accept my answer.

Comment: Yes. I had to manually upgrade the kernel as earlier it could not suspend. This is 16.04 with 8G ram and 8.5G swap space. Everything else except the wifi worked properly(including suspend) in the newer kernel but after your step suspend is broken again.

Comment: Reinstall the original Ubuntu kernel, check your `dkms status`, and if you still have suspend problems, ask a new question.

Comment: Use `iwconfig` to turn off power management on your wireless device and see if that solves your suspend problem.

Comment: thanks @heynnema for your help. I was able to fix the problem. It was related to the graphic card.